# Joomla 1.5.22 stripping html code from article html editor

Tags: joomla

If I create a new article in Joomla 1.5.22, and insert some Youtube video embed code (iframe etc) into the article, then press Apply in the HTML editor popup, I get a message like "article text cannot be empty:.

If I include some paragraph text with the Youtube code, the paragraph is saved and the Youtube code is removed.

Why does this occur?  How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by turning off **code cleanup on save** in the TinyMCE plugin manager.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely useful Joomla! plug-in to mitigate code stripping from Joomla! editors can be found here:

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer

To quote the developer:

"Sourcerer enables you to place PHP and any kind of HTML style code (including CSS and JavaScript) right into your content! Not only in your articles, but also in sections, categories, modules, components, META tags, etc.

You can now just place your original codes right into your WYSIWYG editor. The only thing you have to do is surround the code with the Sourcerer tags."

We are using this plug-in for all our websites whenever we need to insert java script code, etc.